# Great test score but sparse scores using cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

I'm implementing a Random Forest Regressor with the Titanic dataset.

Here is how it looks like:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=123)
reg_rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1)  # by default, 10 trees are used
reg_rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
rfc_train_score = reg_rf.score(X_train, y_train)
rfc_test_score = reg_rf.score(X_test, y_test)
print ('train accuracy =', rfc_train_score)
print ('test accuracy =', rfc_test_score)
```

I obtain the following output:

```
train accuracy = 0.988660049497
test accuracy = 0.942596699112
```

But when I try cross validation on this model :

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score 

scores = cross_val_score(reg_rf, X, y, scoring='r2', cv=5)
print(scores)
```

it gives me:

```
[ 0.57775117  0.88199732  0.69066105  0.90320741  0.87953982]
```

As you can see, scores are very different to one another. 
How can I explain this behavior?

I'm running Python 3.6.x

Comment: Where you got X_test and X_train from? How do you split?

Comment: Forgot to paste a line, question edited! @FlorianH

Comment: Have you tried a different random state?

Comment: Those accuracies are of test fold, from the `cv = 5`. So depending on the partition of data into folds, this can happen.

Comment: I tried a different random state and got the same result. The scores mean is 0.78 is it really supposed to be this far from 0.94?

Comment: I ment a different randomstate for your train_test_split to see if the 94% is so much better than average

Comment: I well understood. I changed random state several times and it gave me 93% at least..

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you get the same behavior if you don't specify the `scoring` on the `cross_val_score`?  i.e. just use the default via `cross_val_score(reg_rf, X, y)`.

Comment: gave me the exact same output.. @Paul